# Timed out waiting for the completion of SASL negotiation between HiveServer2 and the Remote Spark Driver

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

I'm studying CDH 6.3.0 with hive and spark and I'm facing for a problem that held me for a week. 
I already installed it from scratch and nothing solved.

The timeout occurs when I try to select from a table.

Considering this :

```
DROP TABLE dashboard.top10;
CREATE TABLE dashboard.top10 (id VARCHAR(100), floatVal DOUBLE)
STORED AS ORC tblproperties("compress.mode"="SNAPPY");
INSERT into dashboard.top10 SELECT * from analysis.total_raw  order by floatVal DESC limit 10;
```

> Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code
>   30041 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask. Failed to
>   create Spark client for Spark session
>   faf8afcb-0e43-4097-8dcb-44f3f1445005_0:
>   java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Client
>   'faf8afcb-0e43-4097-8dcb-44f3f1445005_0' timed out waiting for
>   connection from the Remote Spark Driver

My guess is that timeout settings are not being taken into account.
And as my test environment, I can have a latency greater than 1s

> Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property:
>   hive.spark.client.server.connect.timeout=90000 Warning: Ignoring
>   non-spark config property:  hive.spark.client.connect.timeout

The container is exiting due to an error :

```
exception: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to connect to HiveServer2.
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:41)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver.<init>(RemoteDriver.java:155)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver.main(RemoteDriver.java:559)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:673)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to connect to HiveServer2.
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.rpc.Rpc$2.run(Rpc.java:120)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:120)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
)
19/08/26 17:15:11 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception: 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:447)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:805)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:804)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1875)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:804)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to connect to HiveServer2.
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:41)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver.<init>(RemoteDriver.java:155)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver.main(RemoteDriver.java:559)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:673)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to connect to HiveServer2.
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.rpc.Rpc$2.run(Rpc.java:120)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:120)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19/08/26 17:15:11 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Deleting staging directory hdfs://masternode.vm:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1566847834444_0003
19/08/26 17:15:16 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

I raised the timeouts (as a test) but no success:

```
hive.metastore.client.socket.timeout=360s
hive.spark.client.connect.timeout=360000ms
hive.spark.client.server.connect.timeout=360000ms
hive.spark.job.monitor.timeout=180s
```

I also double-checked the name resolution on every node, and all is fine, but I'm not using DNS I'm using host file instead.

- SO VM on Clusters: CentOS 7
- Apache Spak version  2.4.0-cdh6.3.0
- Cloudera Version CDH 6.3
- Hive Version: 2.1.1-cdh6.3.0, 
  re1e06dfe7de385554f2ec553009ef8452c5fd25a

Answer (score 0):

At the CDH 6.2: `set hive.spark.client.future.timeou=360;` and,It's solved when after cluster restart!